# benefit of pointer checking of cairo context

Tags: c++, cairo

What happens if we do not check if cairo context exists and what happens if returning false, for example:

```
bool MyClass::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
      if ( !cr) return false;  // what realy happens when we return false?
      // is the function called once again?
}

// approach 2
bool MyClass::on_draw(const Cairo::RefPtr<Cairo::Context>& cr)
{
      // do stuff
      return true;  // works just fine without checking so why to check??
}
```

What is the benefit and why would one check there is a context?

What happens if returning false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#abc9e82a0cb0d78f6044f02305a90b6d5) has documentation for `virtual bool Gtk::Widget::on_draw(const::Cairo::RefPtr<::Cairo::Context>& cr)`. I'm assuming, you're overriding that or something similar. The documentation doesn't say anything about the return value, but states it's the default handler of [Gtk::Widget::signal_draw()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm/stable/classGtk_1_1Widget.html#ad403d2412e76b0d6d45809076c63f3a2). Here's a quote from that documentation:

> Returns
>
> true to stop other handlers from being invoked for the event. % false to propagate the event further.

If `cr` doesn't point to anything, then there's probably no point in invoking further handlers of the draw event. Then again, all handlers that actually use `cr` should probably check it anyway, so I don't think cheking here is necessary. If you have a lot of handlers, returning true when none of them can work may reduce a bit of overhead. I'm guessing that the stopping of events is more useful for controlling the event flow on user action rather than the draw event.

Returning false only if `cr` doesn't point to anything seems weird to me. Returning true without checking should prevent other handlers, so that's a bit strange also.